# In the phrase.."at the request of" .. why do we use 'at'?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

In the phrase.."at the request of" .. why do we use 'at'? I understand it refers to someone specific making a request...but I would like to know why we use "at".

Comment: There needs to be a preposition there to set the role of the NP "the request of ...". The choice of prepositions in particular constructions is notoriously idiosyncratic for a given language. There is rarely an answer to "why".

Comment: Because it is an idiomatic expression.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "At the request of" is usually seen in this way:

At the request of **person**...

Example: At the request of Peter, I flooded the field.

Without *at*, you're left with a dependent clause that doesn't connect to the independent clause -- a comma splice. You don't have a sentence and it doesn't make sense.

Example: The request of Peter, I flooded the field.

Comment: Whether to begin with **at** or not depends on what follows after *the request of Peter*. For example: *The request of Peter was unfortunate* and other similar constructions. Nevertheless, in your example the presence of **at** is imperiously necessary.

Comment: @FeliniusRexThank you!

Comment: Your answer lacks focus.

Comment: Except, really, we'd say: at Peter's request.

Comment: You need to tell the OP that, not me. I was responding to the phrase that he specified. Also, not nice to necro a 2-year old answer...

Answer (score 0):

In *at X*, X is a place or point on an area - and places/points are things that can be used to answer the question "where?"

*At the request of XXX, Y*  - seems to be modeling that the request is "putting you in a place/point where" you must do Y.

Comment: What about answering "how" rather than "where", eh?